# Dynamically selecting principal components from the PCA output

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, pca

This seems a trivial problem but i am unable to get the issue resolved!

I have taken numeric columns of iris data set ..then normalized it as below

```
newiris<-iris[,1:4]
iris.norm<-data.frame(scale(newiris))
head(iris.norm)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1   -0.8976739  1.01560199    -1.335752   -1.311052
2   -1.1392005 -0.13153881    -1.335752   -1.311052
3   -1.3807271  0.32731751    -1.392399   -1.311052
4   -1.5014904  0.09788935    -1.279104   -1.311052
5   -1.0184372  1.24503015    -1.335752   -1.311052
6   -0.5353840  1.93331463    -1.165809   -1.048667

# performed PCA now
pccomp <- prcomp(iris.norm )
summary(pccomp)
a <- summary(pccomp)
df<- as.data.frame(a$importance)
df <- t(df)
df
##     Standard deviation Proportion of Variance Cumulative Proportion
## PC1          1.7083611                0.72962               0.72962
## PC2          0.9560494                0.22851               0.95813
## PC3          0.3830886                0.03669               0.99482
## PC4          0.1439265                0.00518               1.00000
```

Now converting rownames into a column for df so that PCs which were rownames forms the first column for further manipulation

```
   library(tibble)
   library(dplyr)
   df<-rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(df), var="PrinComp") %>% head
   df
   ##   PrinComp Standard deviation Proportion of Variance Cumulative Proportion
   ## 1      PC1          1.7083611                0.72962               0.72962
   ## 2      PC2          0.9560494                0.22851               0.95813
   ## 3      PC3          0.3830886                0.03669               0.99482
   ## 4      PC4          0.1439265                0.00518               1.00000

 # Now will be selecting only those PCs where the cumulative proportion is say less than 96%
# subsetting
pcs<-as.vector(as.character(df[which(df$`Cumulative Proportion`<0.96),][,1])) # cumulative prop less than 96%
pcs
## [1] "PC1" "PC2"
```

Now i am creating a PC data frame statically of  vector scores from the first 2 principal components which we got from the above condition (cum prop<0.96)

```
 x1 <- pccomp$x[,1]
 x2 <- pccomp$x[,2]
 pcdf <- cbind(x1,x2)
 head(pcdf)
##             x1         x2
## [1,] -2.257141 -0.4784238
## [2,] -2.074013  0.6718827
## [3,] -2.356335  0.3407664
## [4,] -2.291707  0.5953999
## [5,] -2.381863 -0.6446757
## [6,] -2.068701 -1.4842053
```

My issue is how can i create the above pc data frame dynamically once i know the no of PCs based on condition such as cumulative proportion say being less than 0.95??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run a while loop on the `df's cumulative proportion` field and append the transformed value till it's less than the required threshold.

```
threshold = 0.96
pcdf = list()
i    = 1
while(df$`Cumulative Proportion`[i]<threshold){
    pcdf[[i]] = pccomp$x[,i]
    i = i +1
}
pcdf = as.data.frame(pcdf)

names(pcdf) = paste("x",c(1:ncol(pcdf)),sep="")
```

The output

```
> head(pcdf)
         x1         x2
1 -2.257141 -0.4784238
2 -2.074013  0.6718827
3 -2.356335  0.3407664
4 -2.291707  0.5953999
5 -2.381863 -0.6446757
6 -2.068701 -1.4842053
```

when the `threshold = 0.999` running the same code gives

```
> head(pcdf)
         x1         x2          x3
1 -2.257141 -0.4784238  0.12727962
2 -2.074013  0.6718827  0.23382552
3 -2.356335  0.3407664 -0.04405390
4 -2.291707  0.5953999 -0.09098530
5 -2.381863 -0.6446757 -0.01568565
6 -2.068701 -1.4842053 -0.02687825
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming you know the number of principle component you want say `i`.you can use

```
a <- sapply(X = c(1:i),FUN = function(X){pcdf[[X]] = pccomp$x[,X]})
```

instead of the whole `while loop section`.
 so for i = 2 you get

```
> head(a)
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -2.257141 -0.4784238
[2,] -2.074013  0.6718827
[3,] -2.356335  0.3407664
[4,] -2.291707  0.5953999
[5,] -2.381863 -0.6446757
[6,] -2.068701 -1.4842053
```

where a is your result.

Comment: wud luv to knw if can further shorten the solutions using apply family functions??

Comment: Assuming you know the number of principle component you want say `i`, you can easily apply the sapply function to get this done. I will put it as an update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always want at least one PC, here is a one-line version

```
p <- 0.96
pccomp$x[,1:nrow(df[which(df$`Cumulative Proportion`<p),])] # first two PCs
p <- 0.75
pccomp$x[,1:nrow(df[which(df$`Cumulative Proportion`<p),])] # first PC
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the gr8 solution provided above:

```
pcs<-as.vector(as.character(df1[which(df1$`Cumulative Proportion`<0.96),][,1])) # cumulative prop less than 96%
 pcs  
 ## [1] "PC1" "PC2"
i=length(pcs) # we get the no of PCs fulfilling the cum prop condition
a <- sapply(X = c(1:i),FUN = function(X){pcdf[[X]] = pccomp$x[,X]})
head(a)

> head(a)
        [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -2.257141 -0.4784238
[2,] -2.074013  0.6718827
[3,] -2.356335  0.3407664
[4,] -2.291707  0.5953999
[5,] -2.381863 -0.6446757
[6,] -2.068701 -1.4842053
```

Done!